# Are the functions of substitute chords different in minor and major?

Tags: chords, functional-harmony

I am studying substitute chords,

and secondary triads with two common notes can substitute primary triads.

I know that a chord, in which the root and third notes are common, has a stronger surrogate
function.

However, I saw an explanation on the [Internet Wiki](https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%B6%80%203%ED%99%94%EC%9D%8C) (Korean) that the chords that substitute different chords depending on major and minor. it is as below

> **major**
>
> ii - Secondary chords / Secondary chords substitute subdominant
> chords, and correspond to Re, Fah, and R in the name of the
> commandment. In general, the form of the first dislocation is widely
> used.
>
> iii - Represents a third chord / dominant chord, and corresponds to
> mi, sol, and si in the name of the command.
>
> vi - It represents the sixth chord / tonic chord, and corresponds to
> Ra, Do, and Mi in the name of the command.
>
> vii° - There is no 7th chord / surrogate chord, and according to the
> name of the command, it corresponds to Si, Re, and Pa. Since it is a
> reduced triad, the resonance of the basic position is unstable, so it
> is generally used in the form of the first potential.
>
> All standards are in C major.
>
> **minor**
>
> In minor, the direction of use of chords on the same intervals
> depending on the harmonic minor scale, natural minor scale, and
> melodic minor scale.
>
> ii° - Secondary chords / Secondary chords substitute subdominant
> chords and correspond to Si, Re, and Pa in the name of the
> commandment.
>
> III+ - Represents the third chord / dominant chord, and corresponds to
> do, mi, and sol♯ in the name of the command. Since it is an augmented
> triad, I tend to use 'do' as a non-harmonic consonant and resolve it
> with V rather than being used independently.
>
> III5♮ - 3rd chord / Tonic chord, and corresponds to do, mi, and sol in
> the name of the command.
>
> VI - 6th chord / It Secondary chords substitute subdominant chords,
> and according to the name of the commandment, it corresponds to F, D,
> and Do. Only when used in the deceptive cadence, it substitutes for
> the tonic chord.
>
> vii° - There is no 7th chord / surrogate chord, and it corresponds to
> sol♯, si, and re according to the name of the command.
>
> ♮VII - 7th chord / 'Once' represents the dominant chord, and
> corresponds to sol, si, and re in the name of the command. However,
> rather than maintaining the functionality within the minor key, it
> tends to be used as a V in the major key when the harmonious flow is
> converted into the context of a parallel major key.
>
> All standards are A minor.

---

**What I'm particularly confused about here is that VI is described as a substitute for subdominant in minor, so why is it different from major?**

Comment: I see you've posted a bounty. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Aaron Because someone might know why they explained it that way.

Comment: Well, without knowing what the author was thinking, I'd say it's just not a reliable source. These are basic, well-known functions of the `vi` chord in both major and minor.

Comment: @Aaron It's a very unreliable source, but may have omitted some explanation there. And I put it on the bounty because I thought might be able to catch what someone omitted here. Just give me a chance. I'll wait and accept your answer if no answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vi and VI chords in major and minor, respectively, may both substitute for the tonic (in a deceptive cadence) or the subdominant. Why the text mentions these functions only for minor is not clear.